# Reentry to USA from Canada after flying into Canada from Belgium

Tags: schengen, canada, international-travel, us-citizens

I'm a US citizen staying in Germany.  My family has a summer home in Canada.  I'm thinking of going to Canada this summer, and then going back to the US by driving from Canada into the US.  I don't think this should pose any problems, but it's admittedly a convoluted way of going back.  Anyone know if this is 'fine' and just a regular border crossing?  Or do I need to give details of my entire time in Germany to US immigration?

I should clarify that I've been in Germany for the past three years studying.  Last time on reentry to US airport wasn't a big deal, but they did require verification of identity etc.  I know though that at the border between Canada and US they usually ask for some details of your trip and what you did.  I guess I just give details about the time in Canada then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're a US citizen. You should have no problem getting back into the US. If they ask you about where you've been, just tell them. It's not like you have anything to hide.

Comment: It wouldn't even be a problem for an EU citizen.